# UIView embedded only in UINavigationController and UITabBarController, why?

Tags: iphone, ios, view

In iOS, why can a UIView (and others) be only embedded in a UINavigationController or UITabBarController? What's special about these two classes?

Edit: oops, wanted to ask 'UIViewController' instead of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not true. UIView is embedded with UIViewController. This class provides life cycle for UIView. It takes responsibility from initializing the view to deallocating the view.

UINavigationController and UITabBarController are just derived from UIViewController. They provide extra functionality for building hierarchy and switching between hierarchy respectively.

Answer (score 0):

UIView can be embedded in any ViewController or its subclass. UINavigationController and UITabbarController are nothing but subclasses of UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think the embedding you're referring to is the `embed in` menu item which only allows for `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`. This means that XCode will take your `UIViewController` subclass and embed it in one of these two controllers. They are special because they are controllers of other controllers (collections of UIViewControllers). Xcode is simply taking some of the pain out of building a view controller and then adding it to a navigation controller or a tab bar. You can easily `embed` it in one of these with one click and no code. Much easier than in past versions of XCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about "embed" as in Interface Builder, yes, as of iOS 5, Interface Builder only gracefully designs user interfaces for three view controller containers, `UINavigationController`, `UITabbarController`, and `UISplitViewController`. These are the three container controllers that come out of the box. You can, though, do your own view controller containment. See [Session 102 in WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) for information on view controller containment. Also refer to the section on view controller containment in the [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81).